# Provision certficate to LAMP EC2, which are autoscaled on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, provisioning

I need to design a solution, where the AWS EC2 has LAMP installed . The EC2s are autoscalled . The EC2 should have HTTPS for LAMP . The certificate can be self signed , but the private key should be protected. That is the private key should not be hardcoded on EC2 instance ( which is not best practice) . Also the HTTPS  should originate from EC2 and not from ELB,CloudFront,ACM etc.

Can someone help me in suggesting best practices ?

Answer (score 1):

I would question why you feel you need to terminate SSL on your EC2 instances rather than on the load balancer.

If you require end-to-end encryption of data in flight, you can communicate between ELB and EC2 by using self-signed certs on EC2.

This means you don't have to deploy your private keys to EC2.

Comment: Need to terminating SSL on ec2 is as per security policy - backed by compliance requirement.

Comment: So if you get a public, commercial cert - either purchased or via ACM - can you use that on ELB, and then use a self-signed cert on EC2 to encrypt the entire path?   If you are running a high-compliance workload, you may want to look at CloudHSM for offloading SSL.  Deploying private keys to EC2 instances is generally a poor security practice.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario: Amazon best practices is to store your SSL server certificate in IAM.

> IAM securely encrypts your private keys and stores the encrypted version in IAM SSL
>   certificate storage. IAM supports deploying server certificates in all
>   regions, but you must obtain your certificate from an external
>   provider for use with AWS. You cannot upload an ACM certificate to
>   IAM. Additionally, you cannot manage your certificates from the IAM
>   Console.

[Working with Server Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html)

Are taking an Amazon cerfication? If I remember correctly, this was a question on one of the exams (maybe the SAA).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Private key in an encrypted S3 bucket that only the IAM role of the EC2 instance has access too. In user data for the EC2 instance have it pull down the cert and place it in the proper directory. You can build an AMI that has a LAMP stack already installed.

[EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data)

[S3 server side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html)

[EC2 instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html)

Comment: Do you think thats a good design ? S3 storing certificate , v/s KMS storing certificate (max of 4KB).

Comment: @RajDev no a better practice like every one is saying is to use self signed certs between elb and ec2.